# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider

Tags: java, android, linux, sdk

Mi problema ocurre cuando instalé Android SDKManager en mi maquina Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. En la instalación no hubo problemas, pero cuando quise ejecutar el comando sdkmanager me sale el siguiente error:

```
> sdkmanager
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:670)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:652)
```

Entiendo que es un error causado por mis versiones de Java y según investigué en varios foros, la versión tanto de java como javac deben ser las mismas. Instalé Java JDK 1.8.0_322:

```
> javac -version
javac 1.8.0_382
> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_382-8u382-ga-1~20.04.1-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)
```

Sin embargo esto último tampoco me funcionó. Intenté instarle otras versiones de Java e intercambiar de versión (usando *sudo update-alternatives --config javac; sudo update-alternatives --config java*), pero tampoco tuve resultados.

Alguien ha visto algo similar? Gracias!

Comment: Tienes Java8 y el mensaje indica que estás corriendo algo que se compiló para Java11.

Comment: Intenté desde la versión 8 hasta la 17, en todas las versiones obtengo el mismo error. Cuando ejecuto sdkmanager con Java 11 el error es el siguiente: `com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 54.0`. La versión de Java con la que probé: openjdk 11.0.20 2023-07-18

Comment: version 61 es Java 17. No sé qué más tienes, pero tienes que instalar / disponer una versión que te permita ejecutar todo eso (vuelve a probar java17) y asegúrate de que sea la versión disponible para tus procesos (usa update-alternatives y luego revisa con java -version). Luego [edit] la pregunta y nos cuentas qué sale

Answer (score 0):

Me toco mismo error en windows, tenia jre, jdk habia conflicto entre ambos, jre anterior, y jdk 21 que ya viene incluido un jre mas nuevo, solucion borrar jre anterior, ya no hace falta, dejar solo el jdk que ya viene integrado un jre mas nuevo.